# Byte array in POST in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax, phonegap

I am working on a PhoneGap application that makes REST API calls.  The GET calls have been working fine so far but one of the POST requires a byte array of a file as a part of its expected JSON.

```
{  
“FileBytes”: [Byte array of file here]  
}
```

I used FileReader() and readAsArrayBuffer on the selected file.  I wanted to check that the byteArray was going to be what I needed so I tried logging it to the console and I took a look at it in IE.

```
var file = evt.target.files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (function () {
    var buffer = reader.result;
    console.log(buffer);        
    console.log(new String(buffer));

});
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

The first one gave me [object ArrayBuffer]{byteLength: 185955}.
The second gave me [object String]{0: "[", 1: "o", 2: "b", 3: "j", 4: "e", 5: "c", 6: "t", 7: " ", 8: "A", 9: "r", 10: "r", 11: "a", 12: "y", 13: "B", 14: "u", 15: "f", 16: "f", 17: "e", 18: "r", 19: "]", length: 20 ...}

The first one looks like it contains what I want, but I am not sure how to pair that in the JSON to make the POST call.

EDIT: I originally made this application in Android Studio using Java. By turning the bytearray into a StringEntity I was able to get the call to work:

```
entity = new StringEntity("{\"FileBytes\": \"" + new String(byteArray) + "\"");
```

From there I was able to use android-async-http to handle the POST.  The entity was used as the parameter as follows:

```
client.post(getApplicationContext(), url, entity, "application/json", 
    new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
```

I logged String(byteArray) to the console and the result was something like this: JSVYUlhiZWdpbgolJU9JRF9BVFRf...
I am just not sure how to replicate this in Javascript.

Comment: Since JSON is a text format and cannot transport arbitrary binary data you'll have to tell us exactly how the data needs to be sent. Is it `{"FileBytes":[255,224,168,115,79,70,73,70,0,1]}`?

Comment: JSON is a text format. How are you expect to interpret binary data into text? For sure, you can write 0 and 1 symbols of entire array, but the length of the post body would be terrible big. Or as @Musa say, you can write the whole byte, but nonetheless, it's anyway huge

Comment: I originally created this application in Java and I was able to use the following:  
    entity = new StringEntity("{\"FileBytes\": \"" + new String(byteArray) + "\"");